Is it possible to set the framework in launchSettings.json?
I created an Uno platform app and it's running well. By default, there are some profiles for WebAssembly and WinAppSDK, but there's no for android, to run android I need to change the framework manually every time I want to run it.

Is there a way to add a profile in launchSettings.json to set automatically the framework?
Also there's a way to set the Android Local Device if there are more than one?

Were you able to figure this out by chance?  I am trying to figure out how to assign environmental variables to the Droid emulator in Uno.

FWIW I have created a discussion for this on Uno's boards here: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions/19133
